# viewWillAppear is not called

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know that viewWillAppear is not called on pop/push views, but I really need that method. Here is what I try

I added UINavigationControllerDelegate and adopt

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
       [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    NSLog(@"Log");
}
```

but viewWillAppear is still not invoked

EDIT

```
AppDelegate.m

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

    FirstView *fview = [FirstView]alloc]init];
    [self.viewController pushViewController:fview animated:YES];

FirstView.m
....
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
  NSLog(@"Logged");
}
```

....

Comment: "I know that viewWillAppear is not called on pop/push views" where did you get this false information from?

Comment: @Paul.s here http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html

Comment: Well that must some bad or old info. I just created a new `Master-Detail Application`, placed a break point in both the `viewDidAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` and ran the app no modification and both break points fired...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clue is here:

```
  [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
} 

-(void)viewWillAppear
```

You call a method that takes one parameter. But your method doesn't have one. In Objective C terms that's a completely different method.

It should look like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  // blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have navigation controller on window?
paste your appdelegate.m

my working code:

```
self.navController = [[[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[HomeViewController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I have added navController to self.window.rootViewController instead of addSibview

Comment: please, provide sample of your code (navcontroller creating, push, pop)

Comment: I think that in order to make addSubview method we don't need to create UINavigationController. If we create transition level via UINavigationController class we should follow its idioms. Although it may be a realization, but it's a bit breaks the logic of the UINavigationController transition.